# Check if value exist firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to check if there is a cart with a userID but it doesn't seem to be working
[image]

Here is my code attempt, I don't know where I'm going wrong, I have firebase initialized

```
let storage = Cart.shared.firebase
    storage.child("cart").orderByChild("userId").equalTo("Eyo1DCNZU8TfB16zJDuULpKAx2V2").once("value",snapshot => {
                    if (snapshot.exists()){
                      const userData = snapshot.val();
                      console.log("exists!", userData);
                    }else{
                        console.log("nope")
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore) but writing code for [Realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/products/database). Try the code below:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("cart").where("userId", "==", USER_ID).get().then((qSnap) => {
  if (qSnap.empty) {
    console.log("No cart found for user")
  } else {
    console.log("User carts")
    qSnap.docs.forEach((d) => {
      console.log(d.data())
    })
  }
})
```